# getUser return EDAMSystemException errorCode=8

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, oauth, evernote

I'm trying to get my account information by evernote api on python, however, I got  errors :

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File "", line 1, in
>
> File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/evernote/api/client.py", line 148, in delegate_method
>
> File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/evernote/edam/userstore/UserStore.py", line 1033, in getUser
>
> File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/evernote/edam/userstore/UserStore.py", line 1058, in recv_getUser
>
> evernote.edam.error.ttypes.EDAMSystemException: EDAMSystemException(errorCode=8, rateLimitDuration=None, _message='authenticationToken')

My python code as below:

```
from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient
dev_token="my develop token"
client = EvernoteClient(token=dev_token)
userStore = client.get_user_store()
user = userStore.getUser()
```

I'm sure I've generated a valid developer token for my Evernote account, as shown in the picture, I have a develop token in my account [link](http://imgbox.com/XU0ZhiVB)

Is there anything I missed?

By the way, I use the code above and replace the key with another develop token generated by Evernote sandbox account, it's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not on sandbox, try:

```
client = EvernoteClient(token=dev_token, sandbox=False)
```

Comment: Regarding to the api arguments. Is there any document mentioned about the detailed api prototype & arguments??  Evernote official website seems not have such link to explain all api prototypes like this one.